# Express: Resolved Promise going to catch Call

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to send the data from a promise, using Promise chaining the Promise is getting resolved. But the `catch` call is running not `then` call

Here is the code from where I am returning the data using Promise:

```
UserSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function(email, password) {
        const User = this;

        return User.findOne({
            email
        }).then((user) => {
            if(!user) {
                return Promise.reject();
            }

            try {
                return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
                    // console.log(res);
                    if(res)
                        resolve(user);
                    else 
                        reject("Invalid Credentials");
                });
            });
        }
        catch(error) {
            Promise.reject(error);
        }
        });
    };
```

Here is the Promise chain call, where catch call is working not the then call

```
app.post('/users/login', (req, res) => {
    const body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
    // console.log(body);

    User.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password)
        .then((user) => {

        }).catch(error => {
            error.generateAuthToken().then((token) => {
                res.header('x-auth',token).send(error);
            });
        });

});
```

Hi tweaked the code, to have another call on the catch.

Could be there any better solution for that.
It's sure that the data is being returned that means, Promise is resolved.

Comment: So regular `try`/`catch` calls don't catch anything in functions inside them: `let f; try{f = () => throw Error('in function)} catch(e){…} … f()` doesn't catch anything, because `f` ends up being called `outside` the block. Which is why promises have their own catch in the first place. So your first example seems like it isn't doing what you expect, because most of your code in the `try` block is in a function.

Comment: If you use async functions though, regular try catch blocks work like you'd expect, as long as you `await` any async results.

Comment: Could it be possible to write the code changing accordingly, so that it would work?

Can you help me with that?